# Ionic conditional no-lines change

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I change the value of `no-lines` property dynamically in Ionic?

I have tried:

```
<ion-item [no-lines]='condition'> test </ion-item>
```

This gives me an error:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>       Can't bind to 'no-lines' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'.
>       1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component and it has 'no-lines' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>       3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("/div>

Answer (score 3):

`<ion-item [attr.no-lines]='condition'> test </ion-item>`

You need `[attr.no-lines]` instead of `no-lines`.  Also, it's worth noting if you want lines to appear, you need the expression to evaluate to `null` not `false`.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ appName }} 3.4.0</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    Item 1
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item no-lines>
    Item 2
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item [attr.no-lines]="null">
    Item 3
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item [attr.no-lines]="true">
    Item 4
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item [attr.no-lines]="false">
    Item 5
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Items 1 and 3 above have lines and items 2, 4, and 5 do not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add additional attributes to an element using:

```
<div [attr.no-lines]='yourExpression'></div>
```